# How to align content beside every arrow in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<span class="">hi</span><div class="arrow"></div>
<span class="">hellow</span> <div class="arrow"></div>
<span class="">howru</span> <div class="arrow"></div>
```

I want to place the arrow and content in one line. like

For that. Do I need to right the arrow div, every time or is there any way to write the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display: inline-block;  margin: 0 10px;` into `.arrow`

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<span class="">hi</span><div class="arrow"></div>
<span class="">hellow</span> <div class="arrow"></div>
<span class="">howru</span> <div class="arrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there's another way to do it by using CSS Flexbox.

1. You need to create a new `<div>` with a new class. In my case it's `.arrow-row`.
2. Now, you can style `.arrow-row` using `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: row;`. By doing so, you get the same result but it is going to make your life easier for responsive. For example, you could add a media query so in responsive it turns to a column. In addition, you can use other [Flexbox properties](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp) to define how it should behave when you resize the window.

```css
        .arrow-row {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
         }

        .arrow {
          position: relative;
          width: 120px;
          height: 0;
          border-bottom: 10px solid black;
          margin: 0 10px;
        }

        .arrow::after {
          content: "";
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-top: 20px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
          border-left: 30px solid black;
          position: absolute;
          right: -10px;
          top: -15px;
        }
```

```html
  <div class="arrow-row">
        <span class="">hi</span><div class="arrow"></div>
        <span class="">hellow</span> <div class="arrow"></div>
        <span class="">howru</span> <div class="arrow"></div> 
    </div>
```